# How to handle multiple user inputs into a match?

Tags: rust

I'm new to programming and I got stucked while trying to get user's input in a match expression. I read the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html) but I didn't find the answer to my problem.

The idea is simple : the user chooses a game mode (Human Vs Human or Human Vs Machine) then the program asks for the user's name. I don't get any error but the program lets me enter only the second name (player_2) but not the first one (player_1). It's like if the program is not stoping for me to enter the first player name.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
use std::io;
use text_io::read;

fn player_input() -> String {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Wrong input");
return input;
}

fn main() {

    println!("GAME MODE");
    println!("1. Human Vs Human");
    println!("2. Human Vs Machine");

    let game_mode : String = read!();

    match game_mode.as_str() {
        "1" => {
            println!("Player 1 : \n");
            let player_1 = player_input();

            println!("Player 2 : ");
            let player_2 = player_input();
            println!("{} - {}", player_1, player_2);
        },
        "2" => {
            println!("Player 1 : ");
            let player_1 = player_input();
            let player_2 = "Skynet";
            println!("{} - {}", player_1, player_2);
        },
        _ => println!("Wrong input"),
    };
    
}
```

And here is the output I get :

```
GAME MODE

        1. Human Vs Human
        2. Human Vs Machine

1
Player 1 : 

Player 2 :
George

 - George
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong because if I test the same code but without the match expression the program actually stops and lets me enter the first name (player_1) before asking me for the second one (player_2). Maybe match is not the way to do it and I should rather use an if/else ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is definitley not a problem with match. Your problem seems to occur because the `read!` macro doesn't remove the whitespace that causes it to end (in this case, \n). Then, the first call to `player_input` reads the \n and immediatley stops. Only then does the second call to player_input actually pick up any input. You can fix this in two different ways:

-You can not use text_io and simply rely on the built in std::io, which does remove the \n that caused its call to end

-You can change the `read!` call to also pick up the \n like so: `read!("{}\n")`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)